# HTML form <select> data from database not correctly displayed

Tags: php, mysqli, menu, visible, dropdown

```
            <?php 

        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "voorraad");

        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT leverancier from leverancier");


        echo "<select id='leverancier' name='leverancier' style='width: 30%', color='black'>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['leverancier'] ."'></option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";

        ?>
```

This is the code that I am using, the data is correctly loaded in the `<select>` menu, but the problem is that it is not visible. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7asQ.png) you can see the problem, the 20 records in the database are loaded, but not visible, I can select them, and save them in the database. But there are not visible.

Comment: option value you have put but you forget to put the option name.

Comment: replace this line `echo "<option value='" . $row['leverancier'] ."'>" . $row['leverancier'] ."</option>";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
echo "<option value='" . $row['leverancier'] ."'></option>";
```

To

```
echo "<option value='" . $row['leverancier'] ."'>'" . $row['leverancier'] ."'</option>";
```

You simply forgot to give the option a name.

Comment: Thanks dude! It's working now! Looking at this problem for almost 2 hours!

Comment: No problem, something like this might happen again a few more times

Comment: @SmashingJummy if you can check this as the answer this question can be closed